# set Date to DatePicker and listener for value changing and removing AR prefix

Tags: swift, datepicker

I'm using DatePicker with my country timeZone year month day are okay but there is AP prefix on picker which I don't need how can I get ride of it ?

I have searched a lot but there is nothing about it

update :

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        datepicker2.datePickerMode = .date
        datepicker2.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "IRST")
        datepicker2.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .persian)
        datepicker2.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")
        datepicker2.date=self.minDate
        datepicker2.addTarget(self, action: Selector("datepickerAction"), for: .valueChanged)
}
```

I need my native date and my time zone and this is datePicker initializing

```
func datepickerAction(){

     let date = self.datepicker2.date

let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day,.year], from: date)
let hour = components.month
let minute = components.day
    let yr=components.year
    print(hour,minute,yr)
}
```

this is the listener which is not working properly not change the date. each time print the same date.

screenshot

http://uploadkon.ir/2Ui

Comment: change the [`locale`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker/1615995-locale) property to your custom locale what shows the time using 24-hours format, rather than 12-hours.

Comment: I'm showing only Dates

Comment: Add the code and the screenshot to show the results you are getting from it.

Comment: Update my first post

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to pass the parameter in the function like this...

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        datepicker2.datePickerMode = .date
        datepicker2.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "IRST")
        datepicker2.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .persian)
        datepicker2.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")

        datepicker2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datepickerAction(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
}
```

So, now you can get the date every time that change in the picker...

```
func datepickerAction(_ sender: UIDatePicker){

     let date = self.datepicker2.date

let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day,.year], from: date)
let hour = components.month
let minute = components.day
    let yr=components.year
    print(hour,minute,yr)
}
```